# Use echo area to show which faces are applied to text at point?

Tags: faces, help

When writing a color theme, it would be helpful if the echo area showed which faces are applied to the text at point.

I know I could use `C-u C-x =` to call `what-cursor-position`, but that requires repeatedly invoking this info in a new help window, dismissing that window, moving point, invoking it again, etc.

I'm imagining a minor mode I could activate temporarily to show the faces in the echo area, and automatically update when I move the point.

Does something like this exist, or would I have to write it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text-properties at point using `text-properties-at`.

Using that, you can very simply create a function that prints the face at point, and then add that function to the `post-command-hook`:

```lisp
(defun message-text-properties-at-point ()
  (message (pp (plist-get (text-properties-at (point)) 'face))))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'message-text-properties-at-point nil t)
```

You can evaluate the above code snippet to achieve the behavior you asked for.
The last `t` in the `add-hook`, is to make the hook buffer local (so it only applies to the buffer that 'is current' at the moment of adding the hook; you can use `remove-hook` to remove it again (see its docstring).

I was testing this in an `emacs-lisp-mode` buffer, where the message quickly got replaced by Eldoc messages, in that case you can just turn off `eldoc-mode`.

Of course, if you would like to have this functionality generally easy available, then you can use the code for defining a minor mode for it.

Comment: I have now found that there exists simply `(face-at-point)`. However, if e.g. hl-line-mode is active, then this will not give you the actual text its face properties. So in that case you can still use `(plist-get (text-properties-at (point)) 'face)`.